# Add column to sheet table by macro button

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to add new column to a table in an Excel sheet. It's easy to record a macro then assign it to a button, but my problem that the first row in the table has a blue background, when I click on the button the first cell in the column has white background instead of blue, even though I changed it when I was recording the macro. My code:

```
 Sub AV()
'
' AV Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
    Range("Table5[Column53]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListColumns.Add
    Range("H14").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("H15").Select
     ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, changing `listcolumns.add 2` to the desired column.

```
Sub AV()
'
' AV Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table5").ListColumns.Add 2
    Range("H14").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("H15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need all the code that gets recorded with the macro.  If you just add a column to the table, it should copy the color scheme of the existing table.

The only thing to be certain of is that "Selection" is in a valid table.  The code below checks for that; if Selection is not in a valid table, it uses the last table on the Active Sheet; or returns an error message if there are no tables.

Other alternatives could easily be accommodated to deal with the case where selection is not within a valid table.

Also, the code adds a column to the end of the table -- you could specify a different position for the added column if you want.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub addColumn()
    Dim LO As ListObject
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
Set LO = Selection.ListObject
If LO Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveSheet
    Select Case .ListObjects.Count
        Case 0
            MsgBox "No ListObjects on active sheet"
            Exit Sub
        Case Is > 0  'select the last table on the sheet
            Set LO = .ListObjects(.ListObjects.Count)
    End Select
    End With
End If

LO.ListColumns.Add

'Optional to protect the sheet again, if you want
'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"

End Sub
```

---